# BEM: Best way to have container and row?

Tags: css, bem

I have the following setup for a content block in BEM:

**SCSS**

```
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.latest-news__container {
  @extend .container;
}

.latest-news__row {
  @extend .row;
}
```

**Which compiles to:**

```
.container, .latest-news__container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row, .latest-news__row {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<div class="latest-news">
  <div class="latest-news__container">
    <div class="latest-news__row">
      <div class="latest-news__image"></div>
      <div class="latest-news__content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question:**
Is using @extend for the `.container` and `.row` a good idea in order to keep the class name for the elements as per the block name? Or should I just have `.container` and `.row`? Then have another `@extend` for other blocks and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at mixes concept (when different blocks or elements are mixed on the same DOM node): https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#mix and https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes

So your markup may look like this (which will give you possibility to avoid `@extend` at all):

```
<div class="latest-news container">
  <div class="latest-news__item row">
    <div class="latest-news__image"></div>
    <div class="latest-news__content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, still learning the BEM way :) its just that I wanted to keep .latest-news at 100% width incase I wanted to add a background color or image to that div, container would just be the width of 960px